# creating a directory tree on a remote machine with a specific group ownership

Tags: ssh, directory, group

I just struggle with the problem that I want to create a directory tree on a remote machine in which all directories have a certain group ownership. Furthermore, I explicitely want to have parent directories generated automatically if not existent yet. So what I tried to do by now was:

```
ssh me@remotemachine "newgrp mygroup && mkdir -p /path/to/my/directory"
```

However, it seems not to work to execute `newgrp` on the remote machine via SSH.

Of course another option might be to create the directory first and then change the group ownership afterwards, but this would require that I knew which parent directories were created automatically by the `-p` option of `mkdir`.

So is there a way to either log in by SSH as member of a specific group rather than as member of my default group on the remote machine or, alternatively, to get mkdir telling me which parent directories it created automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`newgrp` starts a new shell, so in your command

```
ssh me@remotemachine "newgrp mygroup && mkdir -p /path/to/my/directory"
```

the `mkdir` will be executed after exiting from the subshell started by `newgrp`.

You could feed your commands as input into the `newgrp` shell, e.g.

```
ssh me@remotemachine newgrp mygroup << EOF
mkdir -p /path/to/my/directory
ls -ld /path/to/my/directory /path/to/my
EOF
```

Comment: This solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `install` command:

```
ssh me@remotemachine "install -g mygroup -d /path/to/my/directory"
```